# How to use or implement __div__ (python2) instead of __truediv__ in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, operators, python-2.x

In python2 you can choose between using __div__ or the __truediv__ operators [see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

In python3, the __div__ operator seems not to exist as it was replaced by __truediv__ entirely. How can I use the original __div__ method in a script that needs to be interpreted by python3 ?

It does not matter if the solution overwrites __truediv__ or is simply a function such as operator.div() or even a wrapper that runs python2 on a portion of a code in a python3 interpreted script (does that even exist ?). I have a script that I need to run with python3 and I have to make *one line of code* that contains the `/` operator work as it would in python2 somehow.

Comment: python3 has [`__floordiv__` (`//`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) and [`__truediv__` (`/`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`__floordiv__`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html).

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return 'floor division, hello world, %s' % self.n // other
```